# Custom Video player chapters don't work all time

Tags: reactjs, video

I've created a custom video player with a chapters feature. We use React to fetch and display all.
The client has posted two videos of 2 hours on the same page.
The problem is that when the connection of the user is too slow, the chapters don't appears for one of the video, and sometime for the two of them.

The datas are really well fetched. I asked my manager if a solution like lazy loading could be interesting, but he's not convinced. Is there another solution that could be used ?

I expected that the chapters could not be loaded in one time.

Comment: **What is your video format**? Playback problems can be related to the format being used. _"I expected that the chapters could not be loaded in one time."_ Are you saying that the problem is... you must wait until the video (chapters) are all fully downloaded before the video itself now begins to play?